# prometheus fails to start with error on Windows

Tags: yaml, prometheus

I am trying to run the prometheus for wmi exporter with below configuration. But its failing with error :

ts=2022-06-27T16:04:42.665Z caller=main.go:450 level=error msg="Error loading config (--config.file=prometheus.yml)" file=C:\prometheus\prometheus.yml err="parsing YAML file prometheus.yml: yaml: line 31: did not find expected key"

Any idea what could be the issue?

below is my prometheus.yml

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "prometheus"

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]


- job_name: "wmi_Exporter"
  static_configs:
    - targets: ["10.10.10.1:9182"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong on line 31 onwards. YAML is very very strict about spacing.

Fixed:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "prometheus"

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]


  - job_name: "wmi_Exporter"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["10.10.10.1:9182"]
```